# pandas.interval_range for partial interval

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `pd.interval_range` to generate hourly intervals within a pair of timestamps:

```
In [1]: list(pd.interval_range(pd.Timestamp('2019-02-06 07:00:00'), 
                               pd.Timestamp('2019-02-06 08:00:00'), freq='h'))
Out[1]: [Interval('2019-02-06 07:00:00', '2019-02-06 08:00:00', closed='right')]
```

Is it possible to generate an interval shorter than 1 hour when the end time does not fall on an hour boundary?

In other words, when I move the end time by 1 minute I'm getting this:

```
In [2]: list(pd.interval_range(pd.Timestamp('2019-02-06 07:00:00'), 
                               pd.Timestamp('2019-02-06 08:01:00'), freq='h'))
Out[2]: [Interval('2019-02-06 07:00:00', '2019-02-06 08:00:00', closed='right')]
```

I'd like to get this instead:

```
In [2]: list(pd.interval_range(pd.Timestamp('2019-02-06 07:00:00'), 
                               pd.Timestamp('2019-02-06 08:01:00'), freq='h'))
Out[2]: [Interval('2019-02-06 07:00:00', '2019-02-06 08:00:00', closed='right'),
         Interval('2019-02-06 08:00:00', '2019-02-06 08:01:00', closed='right')]
```

Comment: Tim... just looking at the docs for pandas, it appears that pd.interval_range states that it returns a *fixed frequency* interval.  I think you are requesting a list of intervals that have all one frequency but the last is different.  I don't think this possible unless we try to manually tack on this last interval.

Comment: In the general case I could have a partial interval at the start too (eg hourly intervals from 06:59:00 to 08:01:00). This page gives a good overview of the different combinations: http://strata.opengamma.io/schedules/#Stubs

Answer (score 3):

Based on Scott's suggestion, here is my solution that puts long stubs at the start and end of the schedule:

```
def interval_range_with_partial_hour(start_time, end_time, freq, closed='right'):
    if start_time == end_time:
        return pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left=[], right=[], closed=closed)

    index = pd.interval_range(start_time.floor(freq), end_time.ceil(freq), freq=freq, closed=closed)
    assert len(index) > 0

    left, right = index.left.to_series().tolist(), index.right.to_series().tolist()
    assert left[0] <= start_time
    assert right[-1] >= end_time

    left[0] = start_time
    right[-1] = end_time
    return pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left=left, right=right, closed=index.closed)
```

Comment: I think this is a good addition and probably could be an enhancement in the next version of pandas with a parameter to allow, "short" intervals. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
start = pd.Timestamp('2019-02-06 07:00:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('2019-02-06 09:01:00')

interval_1 = pd.interval_range(start, 
                               end, freq='h')

interval_out = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(interval_1.left.to_series().tolist() +[interval_1.right[-1]], 
                                            interval_1.right.to_series().tolist() +[end])
interval_out
```

Output:

```
IntervalIndex([(2019-02-06 07:00:00, 2019-02-06 08:00:00], (2019-02-06 08:00:00, 2019-02-06 09:00:00], (2019-02-06 09:00:00, 2019-02-06 09:01:00]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[datetime64[ns]]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find out beforehand what the leftover unit of you interest is. If you are interested in hourly Timedeltas but want to know the leftover in seconds you could for example find out:

```
delta = pd.Timestamp('2019-02-06 08:03:00') - pd.Timestamp('2019-02-06 07:00:00')
delta.seconds % 3600
```

In this case you know that there are some 180 seconds remaining and you might be able to deal with that remaining time properly, for example by appending your list by one additional smaller interval.

Comment: Yep, I think this is the way to go... I can generate intervals with the start time rounded down and the end time rounded up to the nearest hour, then shorten the first and last intervals to the correct start and end times.